# iOS 13 APNS with PHP

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications, ios13

iOS 13 now requires you to add the header of apns-push-type for either alert or background.  How do I add this to my current code that I use to send notifications?

I've been sending push notifications using this solution for years but I don't know how to add the headers they're requiring.

````
function sendPushNotification($uid,$title,$message,$action,$type,$id){

$deviceToken = "*************";
$passphrase = '***********';

$ctx = stream_context_create();

stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'pem/Certificates.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

// Open a connection to the APNS server

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

//echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => array(
        'title' => $title,
        'body' => $message,
        'action-loc-key' => 'Bango App',
    ),
    'mutable-content'=> 1,
    'badge' => 1,
    'content-available'=>1,
    'sound' => 'oven.caf',
    'action' => $action,
    'type' => $type,
    'id' => $id,

    );



// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));


fclose($fp);

// Close the connection to the server

}

?>```
````

Comment: I am facing same issue, have you found any solution for this? Please share if you found anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass header along the $msg, in my code i have:

```
$msg = pack("C", 1) . pack("N",$row['id_device_token']) . pack("N", $apple_expiry) . pack("n", 32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $row['device_token'])) . pack("n", strlen($payload1)) . $payload1;
```

where $row['id_device_token'] is "apns-id" and $apple_expiry is "apns-expiration".
According to Apple ([Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns))
the "apns-push-type" header must be placed before "apns-id", so:

```
$msg = pack("C", 1) . pack("N","alert") . pack("N",$row['id_device_token']) . pack("N", $apple_expiry) . pack("n", 32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $row['device_token'])) . pack("n", strlen($payload1)) . $payload1;
```

Comment: I have tried this approach but it is not working for me. No error no notification. Even Apple docs ask 3 required fields. In you answer I found only "apns-push-type".

Comment: Did you modify also client side notification code? The way now Apple return device token is different in iOS 13. Read this: https://onesignal.com/blog/ios-13-introduces-4-breaking-changes-to-notifications/

Comment: Yes, I have modified. I have asked question as well. see this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58543104/ios-13-php-script-payload-for-push-notification